# Getting ScreenMetrics in a NativeScript Angular App

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How do you get access to [`ScreenMetrics`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_platform_.screenmetrics.html) in a NativeScript Angular 2 app?

Is one supposed to use the DI system of Angular, injecting ScreenMetrics? I guess not, because although the `Import` statement is fine, the following doesn't work. I'm seeing strange errors in the console.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ScreenMetrics } from 'platform';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private screenMetrics: ScreenMetrics) {
    console.log(screenMetrics);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the docs aren't very polished, and most code samples are in Plain JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NativeScript Angular to get information about the screen you should use `import { screen } from "platform"`. Then you have mainScreen, though which you  will have access to `heightDIPs`, `heightPixels`, `scale`, `widthDIPs`, `widthPixels` properties. In the example below you could review, how you could access them in NS Angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { screen } from 'platform';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'components/home/home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.dump(screen.mainScreen);
    console.log(screen.mainScreen.widthPixels);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up wrapping `platform` into an `Injectable` Angular service.